# Linq : problem with primary key

Tags: linq-to-entities

I get the following error message

> The table/view 'TABLE1' does not have
>   a primary key defined and no valid
>   primary key could be inferred. This
>   table/view has been excluded. To use
>   the entity you will need to review
>   your schema, add the correct keys and
>   uncomment it

when I try to add a view to an Entity Data Model. For testing, I have created a very simple view and I still get the error. below is the view definition

```
SELECT 
   DISTINCT TOP (100) PERCENT 
   MIN(id) AS Expr4, MIN(EmpNo) AS Expr1, 
   MIN(Name) AS Expr2, MIN(Category) AS Expr3
FROM  dbo.MYView1
GROUP BY id
```

does any one know of a simple work around.

I have looked at this thread [Can SQL Server views have primary and foreign keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/745341/can-ms-sql-views-have-primary-and-foriegn-keys) but in my scenario, what is recommended is not applicable.

If I could only have the view added to the Model.

Comment: Please edit the title of your post to something shorter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your view doesn't have a primary key *constraint,* you need to help the EF out a little. You do this by [editing the CSDL](http://blogs.msdn.com/alexj/archive/2009/09/01/tip-34-how-to-work-with-updatable-views.aspx). You only need to do the first part if you don't intend to update.

Answer (score 0):

Set a primary key for the table.

Comment: "id" is the tables primary key

Answer (score 0):

According to [Social MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/9293cf4d-deef-40b1-ab56-a0ee1e770dd9) this is caused by an Entity Framework bug.