# Warning Error 6002: The table/view does not have a primary key defined

Tags: sql, entity-framework, t-sql, entity-framework-4

This topic is here several times but no answer give me option how to avoid this issue in EF.

My warning:

> Warning       Error 6002: The table/view 'ADContainersWithEnvironmentsView'
>   does not have a primary key defined. The key has been inferred and the
>   definition was created as a read-only table/view.

Basicly I'm using database first approach with EF in my project.

I have view:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].ADContainersWithEnvironmentsView
AS
WITH ADContainerWithEnvironments(Id, LinkedEnvironmentId)
AS
(
    SELECT adc.Id, adc.LinkedEnvironmentId
    FROM ADContainer AS adc
    WHERE ParentAdContainerId IS NULL

    UNION ALL

    SELECT subAdc.Id, parentAdc.LinkedEnvironmentId
    FROM ADContainer AS subAdc
    INNER JOIN ADContainerWithEnvironments parentAdc
    ON subAdc.ParentAdContainerId = parentAdc.ID
)
SELECT ISNULL(Id,-1) AS Id, LinkedEnvironmentId FROM ADContainerWithEnvironments
```

As was explaind in other topics I NEED TO specify PK in my view with **ISNULL(Id,-1) AS Id**

I also mark in Diagram my **Id as Entity Key** check my screenshot
[image]

This warning I have for all my 10 views.
After my changes I close my visual studio, even restart pc, or try it on other pc :) but warning is still there.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error 6002: The table/view does not have a primary key defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24792259/error-6002-the-table-view-does-not-have-a-primary-key-defined)

Answer (score 1):

You get the warning because the view does not have a Primary Key in the same sense as tables have them. As you probably won't be inserting anything in the view you can ignore the warning and use the view for just querying.