# View Doesn't have Primary Key Defined warning in entity framework despite having a primary key?

Tags: entity-framework, view, ef-database-first

I'm using entity framework in my project with a database first approach. I'm seeing that whenever I try to add a view to the EDMX, despite the view having a primary key column in it, I see a warning in the error list that says that view doesn't have a primary key defined. See below screenshot.

[image]

As you can see in this example which I tried, the view does have a primary key column included in it. The view gets added to the EDMX but I see this warning so I'm just curious to know why this warning is shown despite the view having a (primary) key column.

Also, I referred to [this SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33474632/2377928) which is kind of similar to my question and the answer mentioned there says

> "...view doesn't have primary key in the same sense as tables...."

Is this something to do with clustered index or something like that?

Can someone please help me understand what is it that Entity framework looks for in a view and how this warning could be resolved?

Many thanks!