# Oracle and EF - Error : "The table/view does not have a primary key defined. The Entity is read-only"

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, entity-framework, insert

I am trying to insert in Oracle table using entity framework. I am able to retrieve data but I am not able to insert data into the tables. Following is the error I receive when trying to insert data.

```
+       InnerException  {"The table/view does not have a primary key defined. The Entity is read-only"} System.Exception {System.InvalidOperationException}
```

I have primary keys in all the tables which also means the "Entity Key" checked. I have tried deleting the tables and adding it back again, I also tried recreating the .edmx file, but the error persists. I am using VS 2012 and .net framework 4.6.1.

Any suggestion which will help solving this error are appreciated. I have done lot of research and have tried all the suggestions available on related posts but the error still persists.

Comment: This link might help you out. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24792259/error-6002-the-table-view-does-not-have-a-primary-key-defined

Comment: @JSapkota I have tried the suggestions in this post. Didn't worked. Also, I am not getting warnings it is a error breaking my code.

Comment: @Programmermid : Any success on this. Are you able to resolve this issue. If yes let me know the solution.